# How to redirect log file content to systemd journal?

Tags: systemd, journal

I have a program that accept a `--log-file` parameter. I want to wrapper this program into a systemd service, and write the log to the journal.

The program can run in daemon mode, and supports restart and stop actions.

I found a `systemd-cat`, but it only accept a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `bash` feature of [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
myapp --log-file >(systemd-cat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put following command in `ExecStart` of service unit file

```
myapp --log-file /dev/stdout
```

Comment: Tried, got `ERROR    [Errno 6] No such device or address: '/dev/stdout'`

Comment: My bad.i didn't know that stdout is symlinked to journald socket on which open syscall doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Building off Mark Stosberg suggestion. What worked for me was to use process substitution with bash.

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/location/app --log >(systemd-cat)'
```